# Is there an equivalence for visual studio "microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0" folder in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

For example, where to this "test.ini" file is going to be copied?

```
File.Copy(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") +"test.ini", "test.ini", true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv (64 bit OS) or Windows\System32\inetsrv (32 bit OS).
got it by `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` !

Answer (score 0):

As you are copying the file into the same directory again so the file will be overwrite.

`File.Copy(String, String, Boolean)` Copies an existing file to a new file. Overwriting a file of the same name is allowed.

In your case you are overwriting the file with the new file. Hopefully now its clear to you.

```
File.Copy(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") +"test.ini", "test.ini", true);
```

You are providing the source path with the source file name in first parameter,
in second parameter provide the destination file name and in the third parameter which is a boolean for overwriting the existing file with the new file when it is true.

Comment: but the HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/") +"test.ini" is the source not the destination

Comment: I have edited my answer. It might solve your problem.

Comment: Actually, I don't think you are right. I tried this one: System.IO.File.WriteAllText("anothertest.ini", "sth"); and the file was not saved in the root directory.

Comment: You just asked where the file will be copied, and the way you are using file copy function is just for overwriting a file.
[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5(v=vs.110).aspx)